# Why isn't the saturation current of a photodiode the same as its short circuit current?

Tags: photodiode, saturation, optoelectronics

The formula I see everywhere is:

$$
I_{sat} = \frac{V_{bias}}{R_L}
$$

But this seems incomplete for the following reason:

The larger the resistance is the smaller the saturation current, it stands to reason then that if it was zero, we would have the greatest current the device can physically produce, but if you see the short circuit current of any photodiode [like this one](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s1227_series_kspd1036e.pdf) (second table in the data sheet) it will be very low, microamperes in this case, instead of microamperes as one would expect.

How then can I calculate the highest saturation current of a photodiode and how is it different from the saturation current?

Comment: Where specifically do you see that formula?

Comment: For instance at chapter 2.3.5 of "Optoelectronic Sensors" by Didier Decoster and Joseph Harari https://imgur.com/a/7QB8O95 Also, in this Thorlabs guide https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Photodetector_Lab.pdf

Comment: Your formula for Isat clearly doesn't apply when the photodiode is used in photovoltaic mode.

Comment: On what page of that thorlabs document did you see the formula in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Saturation current is the current at which increasing optical power does not produce increasing current. Combined with the sensitivity curve, it establishes the maximum optical power which the PD can measure.

Short circuit current, on the other hand, is specified at a particular optical power - in the case of your link, 100 lux.

So, short circuit current provides an indication of how much current you'll get (for proper detection circuitry) at some specified optical power. Saturation current determines the maximum optical power you can measure.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not massively misunderstanding something, this is a _completely_ different meaning of saturation current than that used in the Shockley diode equation, right?

Comment: @Hearth - Yes. See, for instance, https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Photodetector_Lab.pdf

Comment: Okay. Good to know I'm not going even further insane, then.

Comment: @Hearth - Saturation current in the Shockley sense simply does not apply to how PDs are used. A standard diode simply does not produce current in the absence of an applied voltage - but a PD does. So the Shockley diode does not apply (operationally - it does apply for a PD in the dark, but that's not how you use them).

Comment: I don't know that much about photodiodes, so I wouldn't have been too surprised if that saturation current showed up somewhere in the equation for photocurrent. That said, now I know that it does not!

Comment: Is there a way to calculate \$I_{sat}\$ without \$R_L\$?

Comment: @FernandoFrancoFélix - Probably, but it would be a difficult task. You'd need to model the absorption of light into PD, and calculate the electron production. At any rate, it's not something you can model from data sheet parameters - other than looking at the graph if the data sheet provides it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I don't care if it's difficult, I have to do it, it's just that I don't know how, could you more explicit?, what graph do I need?. By the way, I actually already have the electron production, and used it to calculate the minimum detectable signal, but the saturation current seems to be a different beast entirely.

Comment: @FernandoFrancoFélix - "what graph do I need?" See the second comment in this thread for an example. "I have to do it" Say what? Why? Are you asking for homework help? If so, review your course material.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast This is not homework, this is a project I'm doing on my own. What are my options if I don't have such a graph?.

Comment: @FernandoFrancoFélix - Buy a couple and experiment. Look - you are going to build a system, right? Actual physical parts and all? Then you must not be afraid to get your hands dirty, and you must learn to keep a watchful, wary eye on theory and simulation. The real world is far more complex than any model, and will bite you on the ass if you ignore it. "All models have limitations. Some are useful."

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast This may not be homework, but it's work, and my boss wants to know as well as possible how everything is going to work before we buy a single thing, so I can't get my hands dirty even if I wanted to

Comment: @FernandoFrancoFélix - Time to change bosses, I'm afraid. He wants you to guarantee results on a matter where you have no experience. This does not bode well for your future at this company. You are going to have to say, "Look. I've never done this before and I can't tell you if it will work." Or just get another job.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That's not an option. I can acquire the expertise needed, which books should I read?, because even some good books like "Optoelectronic Sensors" by Didier Decoster and Joseph Harari don't address this particular issue, as I said in my question, they all present the exact same formula.